# UrabanAirship on carthage

Tags: ios, urbanairship.com, carthage, ios-library

Trying to use carthage for UrbanAirship using this command

```
github "urbanairship/ios-library"
```

I get this error

```
*** Skipped building ios-library due to the error:
Dependency "ios-library" has no shared framework schemes
```

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UrbanAirship put in Carthage support in v7.x.

All is well...